# Container format for ETC1 textures

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, textures

I'm looking for a format that supports mipmaps, cubemaps and 3d textures for using on a OpenGL ES 2.0 game. On Windows, I was using .dds format because of its support for DXT compression. For mobile programs, I think there are .pkm files which don't supports multiple textures and .pvr files which I 'think' dependent on PowerVR platforms. So;

-Can I use .dds with ETC1 compression? Is there a license issue that prevents me to use .dds on platforms other than Windows?

-Do other GPU vendors' products(Adreno, Mali etc.) support .pvr files? (Not PVRTC, just .pvr with ETC1 compression)

-Or is there another file format that I can use for my needs?

Comment: I think that OpenGL ES 2.0 doesn't supports 3d textures (specification lacks of glTexImage3D/glCompressedTexImage3D)

Comment: Yes but my target platform has the GL_OES_texture_3D extension. I think it's very common on modern mobile GPU's.

Comment: Notice that Mali400 drivers/hw (in SGS2) doesn't support this GL_OES_texture_3D extension.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can use DDS for ETC1. Just invent your own FOURCC code. As far as I know dds is not patented.

No GPU vendor support pvr file format (including PoverVX). GPU vendors care only about compressed texture data (PVRTC, ETC, DXTC), not about file format (png, jpeg, dds, pvr). It is user/application responsibility to parse file format to extract texture data (compressed or not compressed).

You can use any file format that is good for your needs. Invent your own. For example, like this:

```
[4 bytes] - width
[4 bytes] - height
[4 bytes] - format id (1 - etc1, 2 - dxt, 3 - ... whatver)
[4 bytes] - count of images (mipmaps/cubemaps/whatever)
[bytes] - data
```

Answer (score 4):

> Or is there another file format that I can use for my needs?

You might want to look at http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/tools/KTX/
and for program to create KTX files http://www.malideveloper.com/texture-compression-tool.php

KTX format support ETC1 compressed textures with mipmaps. It should support also other compression formats, but I don't know other tools that can do it (I've never need it).

Using libktx you can load textures (with mipmaps) from file/memory to GL objects with "single" line of code. Also it can decompress ETC1 textures to GL_RGB while loading .ktx file, if device doesn't support ETC1 (you need to set GLEW_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture manually like [here](http://www.khronos.org/message_boards/viewtopic.php?f=50&t=4762))

Comment: I tried KTX recently and had some problems initially(I'm the one started the thread on that link actually:). But I'm using it now, thanks. By the way, Imagination's PVRTexTool is a nice compression tool too. And it has much more format support: http://www.imgtec.com/powervr/insider/powervr-pvrtextool.asp

Comment: This PVR-tools looks nice, but for example there is no source code for PVRTexLib, so I cannot use it on Android (which is my primary target platform, dev platform is Win+OGLES2 emulator). I like libktx, because it's simple, free, open-source and cross-platform :) PS. I'm the one who answered to that thread ;)